# Styling Ionic2 templates with local scss

Tags: ionic2

Based on this tutorial I started an ionic2 project from a tutorial template http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/adding-pages/.

After successfully adding a new `mypage.html` and `mypage.ts` page under `/app/pages/mypage` I also wanted to align my objects to center on my page, so I created a `mypage.scss` file with the content:

```
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Also note that I added the class `centered` on the `mypage.html` `<ion-content>` tag.

What I found that when I serve my page the gulp won't compile and add my own styles to `/www/build/css` files. Am I missing something or is it buggy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include it in your `app.core.css` file like this:

`@import "../pages/mypage/mypage";`

The first *mypage* is the name of the folder, and the second one is the name of the file (the extension is not needed)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found that you have to also import your file to `/app/theme/app.core.scss`. Which I don't really think is a good solution from ionic team (even worse I did not see this mentioned anywhere).

I think you could edit the gulpfile to source all the scss files under app directory so you don't have to import every single file to `app.core.scss`